# Query multiple tables at once?

Tags: database, query, mysql, table

I want to query all of the posts in my WordPress multi-site set-up looking for a certain string. This is only being done in Sequel Pro (on the command line) for my own inquisitive purposes but there has got to be a better way than copying and pasting the same query over and over again and just changing the table prefix...

Let's say I have 3 sites, I want to find all of the posts that contain the word foo in them:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_1_posts WHERE `post_content` LIKE '%foo%';
SELECT * FROM wp_2_posts WHERE `post_content` LIKE '%foo%';
SELECT * FROM wp_3_posts WHERE `post_content` LIKE '%foo%';
```

I don't want to have to run 3 queries and concat the results somehow.

What I really want to do is

```
SELECT * FROM wp_1_posts, wp_2_posts, wp_3_posts WHERE `post_content` LIKE '%foo%';
```

but that seems to only be meant for joining. Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: This seems a little more in SQL department if you aren't trying to implement it in WP? :) I have looked what desktop client I use (HeidiSQL) does for multi-table search and it just generates multiple queries.

Comment: I think that is the way to go actually. I was being lazy and wanted to display all the output at once without having to copy and paste so I used a UNION command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM wp_posts, wp_2_posts, wp_3_posts 
WHERE 
    wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%foo' OR
    wp_2_posts.post_content LIKE '%foo' OR
    wp_3_posts.post_content LIKE '%foo';
```

should do the trick.

(Note that in Multisite, there shouldn't be a `wp_1_posts` -- your root site uses `wp_posts` etc.)

Comment: Good idea. And you're correct there is no wp_1_. Silly me.

Comment: That's ok -- every time I loop over my sites, I have to remember that wp_1_posts will throw an error.